# Can you dynamically animate a SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am working on coding my site and I had this great idea to animate my navigation bar which is held in a SVG container. Due to the naturally wavy design, I was going for something similar to the Discord intro, where the waves sweep across the screen while waving. So I was wondering if there was a way I can do that, open to any ideas. JQuery, Java, CSS, anything to help.

I have worked slightly with CSS, but had no clue were to start with Java or JQuery. I am looking for a way to get this working onClick with a Hamburger Menu.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.main_hd_cont {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.25vw;
  left: 1.5vw;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
}

.main_hd_txt {
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  font-family: 'ballet_harmonyballet_harmony';
}

svg {
  filter: drop-shadow(.5vw .5vw .15vw rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
}

.navigation_svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Code Cafe | Home </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/stylesheet.css">
  <!--Fonts from Google Fonts API Directory, all rights reserved to original typographers and the Google Corperation -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Styling for Font Awesome Icon library, for high quality icons visit Font Awesome online -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-g5uSoOSBd7KkhAMlnQILrecXvzst9TdC09/VM+pjDTCM+1il8RHz5fKANTFFb+gQ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Script link for JQuery Libraries and Scroll Magic API(s) -->
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- paste locally stored JavaScript file link here -->
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'ballet_harmonyballet_harmony';
      src: url('ballet_harmony-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('ballet_harmony-webfont.woff') format('woff');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="main_hd_cont">
    <header class="main_hd">
      <h1 class="main_hd_txt">Company Name</h1>
    </header>
  </section>
  <!--SVG Graphic as Navigation holder w/ Hamburger Menu Activation -->
  <section class="navigation_svg">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1920 575" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 575;" xml:space="preserve">
         <style type="text/css">
               .st0{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);}
          </style>
         <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="287.2289" x2="1920" y2="287.2289">
          <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#8C572B"/>
           <stop  offset="0.9974" style="stop-color:#593118"/>
         </linearGradient>
          <path class="st0" d="M57.5,139c52.6,0,272.7-21,509.6,0s515.9,0,556.8,0c19.4,0,37.8,8.3,50.7,22.7 c35.5,39.7,120.6,119.2,245.4,136.3c96.7,13.2,176.4,61.6,226.8,100.2c28.6,22,53.6,48.3,74.5,77.7c28.7,40.3,94.9,112.1,194.9,97.7 c2.2-0.3,3.8-2.2,3.8-4.4V-1H0v82.5C0,113.3,25.7,139,57.5,139z"/>
    </svg>
  </section>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

The only thing I've gotten it to do is fade, but hat was a mere test of the `@keyframes` ability to animate SVGs.

Comment: I would look into the [MorphSVG Plugin from Greensock](https://greensock.com/morphSVG). Study the examples and figure out how to apply it on your shape. That should be a good start for you.

Comment: @Miro I would love to use the useful Morph SVG plugin from GreenSock, unfortunately this is a design for a business I am starting and I would need a business class license to do so, currently I don't have the funds for GreenSock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transition the path's d property with css like this:

```css
path {
  transition: d 1s;
  d: path('M547 93.0001C496 38.0001 457 29 372 15C276.086 -0.79759 -57 -52 9.99988 240C33.2036 341.127 87.9999 397 157 366C226 335 285 227 325 341C365 455 407 425 598 412C789 399 841 322 839 233C837 144 688 162 642 169C596 176 598 148 547 93.0001Z'); 
}

path:hover {
  d: path('M547 92C471.994 92 482.5 -39.5 372 14C284.509 56.3601 -57 -53 9.99984 239C33.2035 340.127 82.5699 351.503 157 365C253.5 382.5 248.741 246.296 325 340C401.5 434 445.063 526.153 598 411C768 283 874.5 310 839 232C802.123 150.975 671.067 131.667 642 168C616 200.5 613 92 547 92Z'); 
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 900 500">
  <path d=""/>
</svg>
```

## Using keyframes

```css
path {
  animation: 10s infinite alternate wave ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes wave {
  from {
    d: path("M2,5 S2,-2 4,5 S7,8 8,4")
  }
  to {
    d: path("M2,5 S2,14 4,5 S7,8 8,4")
  }
}



body {display: flex;}
svg {width: 100%;}
path {fill: none;stroke: #000;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
  <path d="M2,5 S2,-2 4,5 S7,8 8,4" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, personal reasons. This snippet with which you've put code, does it give the wavy animation I mentioned? Also, can this be substituted into a keyframes animation by any chance, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can animate a wave and yes you can use keyframes. It's the same thing. You're simply animating the path's `d` property with css.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. I had found a way late yesterday that works sufficiently by using Snap SVG and some JQuery syntax. But your help is still greatly appreciated.

Comment: Awesome. I've never used snap but heard a lot of great things about it. However, you should be aware that you probably don't need jQuery to use it (and you should probably avoid adding two libraries just to achieve one simple effect).